# Button click event not called

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to disable a button, only using javascript.

I have one button on the form. I want to disable that button from javascript. When I try to do this, the button submit click event is not calling.

**I used following code on javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('<%=imgSubmit.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
```

The button get disabled; but its button click event on server side is not being called.

When I remove this javascript then it is calling the server side click event. What is the issue with disabling the button from javascript??

Comment: so what do you actually plan to do? do you want the button to be disabled? in that case the click event will not get fired at all.

Comment: Strange question.  The point of disabling a button is to make it stop generating click events.

Comment: What is it you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Well if the button is disabled it is not going to fire the server side event. Try submitting the form from the client side.

```
document.getElementById('<%=imgSubmit.ClientID%>').disabled = true; 
Form1.submit();
```